# Runing an app in a terminal with a debugger on Linux using Qt Creator

Tags: linux, qt, debugging, terminal, qt-creator

I have simple console application in C++ written in Qt Creator 2.4.1 on Kubuntu 12.04. My app have simple menu  where you choose what you want to do (using `std::cin` and `getline()`).

The problem is that I cannot input data in console in Qt Creator. So I use option "Run in terminal" (xterm). But when I want to run debugger I get "ptrace operation not allowed".

So:

1. In QtCreator console I cannot input data (debugger working)
2. In terminal I cannot use debugger (ptrace operation not allowed)

I need both: input data and debugger.

Any solutions how to handle this?

Comment: Check out this solution too (disable "Run in console"): http://www.deder.at/wordpress/?p=307

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this](http://blog.mellenthin.de/archives/2010/10/18/gdb-attach-fails-with-ptrace-operation-not-permitted/#comment-141535) solution after quick googling:

```
$ sudo su -
$ echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

After doing this, I was able to run the application in debug modus, but the debugger did not stop at my breakpoints. Maybe it will work for your application.

Comment: Its working! Thanks! I was googling too, but without results. In my app debugger stops in breakpoints normally.