# Qt debugger input not working

Tags: c++, macos, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I am trying to learn to debug using Qt Creator on OS X. Some of the exercises I am trying to complete require user input. When run normally the terminal window appears and dialogue works fine. However when run in debugger mode the terminal Windows down not appear and no input can be taken.

I have tried setting a break point and setting the values using the "watches" window (I don't know what it is actually called but that is what Code:: Blocks called it). I have also tried to skip the `cin` lines using the step over button but that does not work either. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343826/runing-an-app-in-a-terminal-with-a-debugger-on-linux-using-qt-creator) which seemed similar but it was for Ubuntu and I am on Mac and I have no idea how implement their fix.

Here is an example of my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
     double base_val;
     cout << "Enter a base value: ";
     cin >> base_val;
     //the code cannot go further than this
     cout << base_val;
}
```

This was done in a plain C++ application with the *qmake* build system.
The Run in terminal option is checked (Projects / Build & Run /Run)

Comment: So you are using Qt Creator? Which version? Also, which OS and (for Windows at least) which toolchain might be useful info.

Comment: Sorry, I am quite the noob: I am using Qt creator 4.0.2 on El Capitan, I don't know which toolchain :(

Comment: Based on Qt 5.7.0 (Clang 7.0 (Apple), 64 bit)

Comment: Well, it works for me under Ubuntu. Terminal window opens, and I can input the number when I step over `cin` line. Make sure you have the *Run in terminal* checkbox checked under Projects view Run settings.

Comment: @hyde I mentioned I have the _Run in Terminal_ checkbox checked, I have tried both ways though. Odd it works for you in Ubuntu, the question I linked seemed similar to mine just in Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, hopefully someone using Qt Creator on OSX can answer... In the mean time, you could see if *Window -> Output Panes -> Debugger Console* shows anything which might give a hint on what is going on (or any other of the panes).

Comment: Another possible way to troubleshoot: start Qt Creator from terminal, and watch its output, in case it prints some error or warning when you start debugging.

Comment: @hyde I have run Qt from terminal and then tried to debug my program but apparently this is not supported, this is what happened:

Comment: `Run in Terminal is not supported yet with the LLDB backend`

Comment: there was more but it was a little too long to put here and that line seemed like the clincher

Comment: Yeah :(. One option might be to run Linux in a VM, if you have to get the exercises done "properly".

Comment: Thanks for the help @hyde ,  I was just repeating some exercises I had for code::blocks, I guess Qt creator is not quite the platform to be trying out these learner exercises with. But still thanks :) I think I might try the linux VM since you have peaked my interest ;)

Answer (score 0):

I managed it to get it running on the 
**qt creator** 
and also with **code::blocks**
but on arch linux - should work in windows and mac osx similar.

I installed **gdb** first but that is a Linux thing - windows and mac should have all on board ready installed with both editors.
(yay -S gdb:)

```
3 extra/gdb 8.3.1-1 (3.8 MiB 9.7 MiB) (Installed)
    The GNU Debugger
```

On Code::Blocks activate `Debug->Debugging Windows->[x] Watches`
On the qt creator it is shown after hitting `F5` or `Debug->Start Debugging->Start Debugging of Startup Project F5` on the right hand side named *name | value*

Both programs creates the same messages, took me a while - I hope that safes you guys time or helps you out if you never found it to